# MySQL json_search on numeric values

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I've got a json list of objects like that

```
[{
    "something": "bla",
    "id": 2
}, {
    "something": "yes",
    "id": 1
}]
```

My `id` field is always a numeric value. But when I try to find `id = 2`, MySQL returns `NULL`

```
select
    json_search(
        json_extract(
            '[{"something": "bla" ,"id": 2}, {"something": "yes","id": 1}]',
            "$[*].id"
        ),
        'one',
        2
    ) as json_search;

json_search |
------------|
            |
```

When I use a string as value in my json `id` object instead of a numeric value, I got a result with Index 0.

```
select
    json_search(
        json_extract(
            '[{"something": "bla" ,"id": "2"}, {"something": "yes","id": 1}]',
            "$[*].id"
        ),
        'one',
        "2"
    ) as json_search;

json_search |
------------|
"$[0]"      |
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7.17

```
@@version  |
-----------|
5.7.17-log |
```

Is numeric search in json arrays not provided in MySQL?

Comment: did you get a solution to query numeric values?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something complicated, not intuitive and possibly with performance problems, but it's an option:

```sql
mysql> SELECT JSON_SEARCH(
    ->   REPLACE(
    ->     REPLACE(
    ->       REPLACE(
    ->         JSON_EXTRACT('[
    '>                         {"something": "bla" ,"id": 2},
    '>                         {"something": "yes","id": 1}
    '>                       ]', "$[*].id"),
    ->       ', ', '","'),
    ->     '[', '["'),
    ->   ']', '"]'),
    -> 'one', '2') `json_search`;
+-------------+
| json_search |
+-------------+
| "$[0]"      |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Ok, that works. But indeed, it doesn't look intuitive and I'm afraid that it will be slow with real datas.

Answer (score 1):

Although the `JSON_EXTRACT` function was returning `[2, 1]` and it was a valid JSON, if you search the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) the `JSON_SEARCH` function is:

> JSON_SEARCH(json_doc, one_or_all, search_str[, escape_char[, path] ...])

So, as I understood you can only work with `STRING` values, and not with numeric values. But one solution to your problem could be to use the `JSON_CONTAINS` function as it returns 1 or 0 if the numeric value exists or not.

```
select
    json_contains(
        json_extract(
            '[{"something": "bla" ,"id": 2}, {"something": "yes","id": 1}]',
            "$[*].id"
        ),
        "2"
    ) as json_contains;
```

The only problem is that you could not get the path to the given value within the JSON document. Hope it helped.

Comment: But then I have to use a string value as search value...also not really satisfactory